# How to use template tag with Vue root instance

Tags: vue.js, html5-template

I am enhancing a page in a web application using Vue.  In the past I have written single file components and I've found it convenient to define the html template at the top of the file using a `<template>` tag.

Is there a way to use this tag when defining a Vue root instance?  Or do I need to put a string in the template property of the Vue options object?

Comment: are you embedding directly into a html page?  not using .vue?

Comment: Share your code which is not working for you ?  Provide live demo ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the x-template syntax, like so

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
  <script type="text/x-template" id="message-template">
        <div >
           {{message}}
        </div>
    </script>
  
  <div id="app"> </div>
  
 <script>
     var graphapp = new Vue({
            el: "#app",            
            data: {
                message: "hi there"
            },
            template: "#message-template"
     });   
  </script>
   
</body>
</html>
```

worth noting, if your editor doesn't understand html inside the x-template block you can use `text/html` also.

You can also define a number of components in the page also.   This is super useful when you are upgrading a page from plain html/js but can't fully change it over

Refer to: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#X-Templates

Comment: But why not simply use HTML5 `<template>` tag?

Comment: @K3---rnc  for IE11, which is often still considered a minimum supported browser.    I know with the commercial websites I run, there are still quite a few IE11 users.

Comment: Those users from central Africa must be converting phenomenally for you, I'm sure. xD

Answer (score 0):

Seems as of 2020, you can pretty much use HTML5  tag [directly](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html):

```
<template v-if="ok">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Paragraph 1</p>
    <p>Paragraph 2</p>
</template>
```

The reason you might not want to use `<template>` in some cases is to avoid invalid HTML5 validation and/or rendering errors (see [Vue.js DOM Template Parsing Caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#DOM-Template-Parsing-Caveats)).