# How to generate Vue components from Javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm new to Vue.js (with a background in Computer Science and programming, including interactive Javascript webpages) and as I'm a teacher, I have a quiz site I use to give homework to my students.

My codebase is messy, so I decided to migrate the whole thing to Vue, with the idea that I could use a component for each individual type of question -- separation of concerns, and all that.

However, I can't seem to find a way to generate appropriate components on the fly and include them in my page.

Here's a simplified version of my framework, with two question types. If I include the components directly in the HTML, they work fine.

```
Vue.component("Freetext",{
            props: ["prompt","solution"],
            data : function() {return { 
                        response:""
                    }},
            methods : { 
                check : function () {
                    if (this.solution == this.response) {
                        alert ("Correct!");
                        app.nextQuestion();
                    } else {
                        alert ("Try again!");
                    }
                }
            },
            template:'<span><h1>{{prompt}}</h1> <p><input type="text" v-model="response"></input></p>   <p><button class="LG_checkbutton" @click="check()">Check</button></p></span>'
        })
Vue.component("multi",{
            props : { prompt: String,
                 options : Array,
                 key_index : Number // index of correct answer
                },
            data : function() {return { 
                        response:""
                    }},
            methods : { 
                check : function (k) {
                    if (k == this.key_index) {
                        alert ("Correct!");
                        app.nextQuestion();
                    } else {
                        alert ("Try again!");
                    }
                }
            },
            template:'<span><h1>{{prompt}}</h1><button v-for="(v,k) in options" @click="check(k)">{{v}}</button></span>'
        })

</script>

<div id="app">

<Freetext prompt="Type 'correct'." solution="correct"></freetext>

<multi prompt="Click the right answer." :options='["right","wrong","very wrong"]' :key_index=0></multi>

</div>

<script>
    var app = new Vue({
            el: "#app",
            data : { 
                        questions:[ {type:"Multi",
                                     prompt: "Click the right answer.",
                                     options:["right","wrong","very wrong"],
                                     key:0},
                                    {type:"Freetext",
                                     prompt:"Type 'correct'.",
                                     solution:"correct"}
                                   ],
                        question_number:0
                    },
            methods : { 
                nextQuestion : function () {
                    this.question_number ++;
                }
            }
        })
</script>
```

But what I want to do is generate the contents of the div `app` on the fly, based on using the data member `app.question_number` as an index to `app.questions`, and the .type member of the question indicated (i.e. `app.questions[app.question_number].type`)

If I try to make the app of the form:

```
{{question}}
</div>
<script>
//...
            computed : {
                question : function () {
                    var typ = this.questions[this.question_number].type;
                    return "<"+typ+"></"+typ+">";
                }
```

...I just get  as plain text, and it isn't parsed as HTML.

If I try `document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = "<multi prompt='sdf'></multi>";` from the console, the tag shows up in the DOM inspector, and isn't processed by Vue, even if I call `app.$forceUpdate()`.

Is there any way round this?

Comment: perhaps you need to read how Vue works again - there's probably a better (in terms of how Vue works) way to do what you are attempting to achieve

Comment: You can also add all your components into html like now but add `v-if="type=='FreeText'"` and show only correct component by question type.

Comment: Also you can use `v-bind:is` like this example https://jsfiddle.net/chrisvfritz/o3nycadu/ from vue docs "dynamic components"

Comment: `<component :is=...` was exactly what I needed. Thanks. 
Don't know why, but all of the sources I'd looked at for Vue were pretty unclear.

My code's working perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe a slightly different approach, Vue supports the concept of "dynamic components"

see https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html

this will let you define what component to use on each question which would look something like

```
<component v-bind:is="question.component" :question="question"></component>
```

Comment: Thanks!
That's exactly what I was looking for, and I don't know how I didn't spot it in the docs.

It gives me the option either to display one dynamically-updated question, or v-for multiple to the screen either simultaneously, or on a one-by-one reveal.

Thanks again -- now my code does what I wanted it to do.

Comment: @NiallTracey since you are using the plain html/javascript approach, there's possibly something else you are missing that you might find useful which I also gave an answer to another question on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50205341/how-to-use-template-tag-with-vue-root-instance/50205427#50205427

Comment: Thanks @Keith -- that's extremely helpful. All the docs on components keep describing the single-file components version and neglect to point out that way of doing it/

Answer (score 0):

While Keith's answer works for most of what I need to do, there's another way to handle this that I've just found out about, which I thought I'd share in case anyone else is looking for it: giving a block level HTML element a `v-html` property.

For me, this is handy as a short term fix as I'm migrating a codebase that generates dynamic HTML as strings, and I can quickly integrate some of my existing code without reworking it completely.

For example, I have a function `makeTimetable` that takes a custom datastructure representing a week's actively and turns it into a table with days across the top and times down the left-hand side, setting appropriate rowspans for all the activities. (It's a bit of a convoluted function, but it does what I need and isn't really worth refactoring at this point.)

So I can use this as follows:

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="freetext-template">
    <span>
        <div v-html="tabulated_timetable"></div>
        <p>{{prompt}}</p> 
        <p><input type="text" v-model="response"></input></p>
        <p><button class="LG_checkbutton" @click="check()">Check</button></p>
    </span>
</script>

<script>
var freetext = Vue.component("Freetext",{
            props: {"prompt":String,
                    "timetable":Object,
                    "solution":String,
            data : function() {return { 
                        response:""
                    }},
            computed : {
                   tabulated_timetable : function () {
                           return makeTimetable (this.timetable);
                   }},
            methods : { 
                check : function () {
                    if (this.solution == this.response) {
                        alert ("Correct!");
                        app.nextQuestion();
                    } else {
                        alert ("Try again!");
                    }
                }
            },
            template:'#freetext-template'
        })
</script>

(I suppose I could put `tabulated_timetable` in `methods` rather than `computed`, as it's set once and never changed, but I don't know if there would be any performance benefit to doing it that way.)
```